# issues with 3 column css displaying incorrectly

Tags: html, css

Got a bit of an issue, I have a 3 column displaying text and check boxes, however it is centering correctly in the page but the boxes and text are centered to

[image: looky here]

I want the content centered in the page but want the text and check boxes aligned correctly vertically. Please help, and thank you!

html

```
<div class="center">
{foreach key=num item=listtld from=$tldslist}
  <div class="column">
      <input type="checkbox" name="tlds[]" value="{$listtld}"{if in_array($listtld,$tlds)} checked{/if}>
      {$listtld}
      {if $num % 5 == 0}
      {/if}
  </div>
{/foreach}
</div>
```

css

```
  div.column {
    width: 30%;                     /* approximately 1/6 */
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;                        /* ie-7 hack for inline block to work */
    *display: inline;               /* ie-7 hack for inline-block to work */
  /*  border: 1px solid red; */         /* temporary - to clearly show the box */
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* to prevent padding issues if you add padding */
    margin: 0;                      /* to ensure the right width */
    vertical-align: top;            /* to line them up evenly across the top */
}
```

Comment: show us the rendered HTML page not the smarty template.

Comment: I just posted an update to your previous and related question.

Comment: i can do this easily with `table`

Comment: What is the CSS rule for `.center`?

Comment: `.center` most likely has !important or is after `div.column` in the page on the css. Correct the problematic one and I don't see why it wouldn't work

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/6cs47/

It's very simple all you have to do is get rid of all old styles and use this new column feature of html5.

```
.con {
    border:1px solid;
    -webkit-column-count:3;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, very much appreciated...also to change widths you gotta put parent , `.con` on `display:inline-block;`

Answer (score 0):

I have created a [codepen](http://codepen.io/lukeocom/pen/wKJbs) for you...

a possible solution is wrapping each input within a div, which gives you greater control over your layout. By setting a fixed width for the divs will ensure that each one is displayed the same, with longer labels wrapping to a second line rather than pushing your alignment out.

```
<div class="center">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="col"><input /><label/></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

hope this helps.

Comment: take a look - http://codepen.io/lukeocom/pen/wKJbs see if you can update it to match what you have? then we can troubleshoot from there...

Comment: @user3646836 By default, the input+label sould be aligned to the left.  This means that there is some other CSS rule affecting the layout.  We don't have all the CSS so we can't fix this without a lot of guess work.  You may have to make the selector highly specific to get the justification to work.

Comment: thats true. It sounds as though the container (div.center) is center aligning the text though.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
{foreach key=num item=listtld from=$tldslist}
  <div class="column">
      <input type="checkbox" name="tlds[]" value="{$listtld}"{if in_array($listtld,$tlds)} checked{/if} style="float:left !important"/>
      {$listtld}
      {if $num % 5 == 0}
      {/if}
  </div>
{/foreach}



div.column {
    width: 30%;                     /* approximately 1/6 */
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;                        /* ie-7 hack for inline block to work */
    *display: inline;               /* ie-7 hack for inline-block to work */
  /*  border: 1px solid red; */         /* temporary - to clearly show the box */
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* to prevent padding issues if you add padding */
    margin: 0;                      /* to ensure the right width */
    vertical-align: top;            /* to line them up evenly across the top */
    text-align:center;
}
```